# What is the probability of a password which consists of $3$ capital letters $(R,P,O)$ followed by $3$ digits is there are restrictions?

Tags: probability, education

**A password consists of $3$ capital letters followed by $3$ digits. What is the probability that a randomly generated password would contain the letters $R, P, O$ if repetitions are not allowed and if repetitions are allowed.**

I'm not sure how to solve this question as I don't know what it means for there to be repetitions and no repetitions in the password and how to determine the probability of the password.

Comment: Repetitions would mean that passwords such as AAA111 would be allowed. No repetitions would mean that ABC123 would be the first allowable password.

Comment: "Repetitions allowed" simply means that for example RRO or PPP would be acceptable letter combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify the question for you.

If the randomly generated password does not follow rules, the problem is not well defined. However if it does, this is the deal.

You have some number of possible passwords allowed with the rule. In you case this is all different passwords with three capital letters followed by 3 digits.

Out of those passwords there are some following the condition for probability. In your case - passwords with letter R O P.

To find the probability you have to find both numbers and divide second result by the first one, i. e. probability is

$$ \frac{number \space of \space all \space passwords \space following \space the \space condition}{number \space of \space all \space passwords \space following \space the \space rule} $$

Now let's speak about details for condition and rule. Any password has this form:

XYZ123

Where XYZ can be replaced with any capital letters from A to Z, while 123 can be replaced with any digits from 0 to 9.

Total number of all passwords starting from

AAA000

to

ZZZ999

is

S = 26 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10

since it contains all possible cases for each letter and each digit.

You can do the math and calculate the number.

Out of those passwords from AAA000 to ZZZ999 there are passwords containing R P O.

It's not clear from the problem whether all letters must be there or not, but if so, there are only 6 cases:

RPO
ROP
OPR
ORP
POR
PRO

Each case has 1000 possibilities with digits from 000 to 999

So the total number of passwords will be P = 6000.

The probability is the number of good passwords divided by the number of all passwords:

P/S = 6000 / (26 * 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10)

Do the math.

In case of any letter from R P O, there are more possibilities such as

APA
BFO
RRZ
etc.

Each one has 1000 cases with digits as well.

You have to calculate all possible triplets of letters, multiply by 1000 and divide by total number of possible passwords in order to get probability.

If repetitions are not allowed, passwords like

AAA000

or

BPB123

or

CDR787

are not allowed because they have repeated letters or numbers.

In order to get probability, you have to:

1. Find / calculate the number of possible allowed passwords such as ABC123 or GQE637 - without repetitions.
2. Out of those passwords find / calculate number of passwords containing R O P (also can be all of them or any of them depending on the problem details)
3. Divide the result from 2 by the result for 1.

As a bonus: think if the probability will change if you ignore digits and solve it for passwords like ABC, i.e. 3 capital letter passwords.